# Cómo animar un punto rojo similar a un un video de grabación sin font-awesome?

Tags: css3

En el siguiente código el punto parpadea en cierto intervalo.

```css
.Blink {
  animation: blinker 1.5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker {  
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger Blink"></i>&nbsp; LIVE </div>
```

Deseo tener el mismo efecto de manera nativa propio CSS, sin utilizar la librería `font-awesome`, ¿Cómo puedo imitarlo sin librerías?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que aporta Font Awesome es que los elemenos con las clases **fa-*algo*** tiene añadido un pseudo-elemento:

```
.fa-circle:before {
    content: "\f111";
}
```

Ese código /f111 no es más que el valor unicode de  (un círculo cuando usas la fuente FontAwesome).

Sin usar esa fuente puedes hacer un círculo usando `border-radius: 50%` en un elemento que sea un cuadrado:

```css
.Blink {
  animation: blinker 1.5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker {  
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

.circle {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    color: red;
    border: 1px red solid;
    width:12px; /*misma altura y anchura*/
    height: 12px;
    
}
```

```html
<div><i class="circle Blink"></i>&nbsp; LIVE </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Y que tal usando un span con un punto, el que está encima del 3 " · " con una fuente a 40 o 50 px y que el texto live tenga fuente normal?

```css
 /* ponemos el tamaño por defecto al div */ 
    div{font-size: 20px;}

    .blink {
        animation: blinker 1.5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
        font-size: 50px !important; /* y aqui le cambiamos el tamaño solo al punto*/
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div><span class="blink">·</span>&nbsp; LIVE </div>
```

Prueba con esto a ver si te funciona bien.